# insert into always encrypted field sqlserver 2016 from php 7.1

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, always-encrypted

I am using PHP, IIS with SQL server 2016 as backend. I am using always encrypted feature. for that I am able to select the data in plain text. but not able to insert the data into the table.
I am using the code like this.

```
$queryInsert = "insert into empinfo (EmpID, JobTitle, LoginID, NatID) values 

(?,?,?,?)";
$res = odbc_prepare($connect, $queryInsert);
$result = odbc_execute($res, array($empId, $jobTitle, $loginId, $natId));
```

I am getting the error like this.

```
PHP Warning: odbc_prepare(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL 
Server][SQL Server]Operand type clash: void type is incompatible with 
nvarchar(256) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', 
encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', 
column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', 
column_encryption_key_database_name = 'Test'), SQL state 22005 in 
SQLDescribeParameter in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\odbctest\odbctest.php on line 22 
PHP Warning: odbc_execute() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean 
given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\odbctest\odbctest.php on line 23
```

can please anyone tell where am I doing wrong.

Comment: Have you followed the DSN configuration specified here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-odbc-driver ?  And provisioned the client keys?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt responce David. Yes , I configured the DSN as per the article you specified and provisioned the client keys as well and that is working fine as I am able to run the select statement from code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try specifying the parameter types as follows

```
/* Construct the parameter array. */  
$employeeId = 5;  
$changeDate = "2005-06-07";  
$rate = 30;  
$payFrequency = 2;  
$params1 = array(  
               array($employeeId, null),  
               array($changeDate, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_DATETIME),  
               array($rate, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_MONEY),  
               array($payFrequency, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_TINYINT)
```

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-odbc-driver) explains how to consume always encrypted using ODBC 13.1 driver

Comment: Hi Nikhil, Thanks for the information. but the article provided uses the sqlsrv drivers but [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlphp/2016/07/11/microsoft-drivers-4-0-for-php-for-sql-server-with-php-7-0-support-released/] does not support always encrypt. So I was trying to use the odbc 13.1

Comment: I see I will remove the link from my answer then. Were you able to provide the parameter types for the parameters when using odbc driver? You might be able to specify the parameter type in the manner I described above.

Comment: No nikhil. I do not see any parameter where I can provide type of parameter in odbc 13.1... Now I am using pdo but that is also not being accepted.

Comment: Have you looked at this article, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-odbc-driver